# using debounce for search input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I have a search input, to make API calls on the fly. I'd like to implement debounce to reduce the amount of server calls.

```
  _debouncedSearch() {
    debounce(this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText), 1000);
  }

  _updateResults(searchText) {
    this.setState({searchText});
    this._debouncedSearch();
  }
```

I am expecting `debouncedSearch` every 1 second. But it is still called on the fly. And throw errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function
>       at debounce (lodash.js?3387:10334)
>
> Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

I feel like this question must get asked around a lot, but none of the solution seems to work for me. Could someone explain to me what exactly is the problem here? I thought debounce is just a setTimeOut.

Thanks

Comment: debounce expects a function as an argument, your `this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText)` probably returns void or something that is not a function, try to debounce a function instead. Using either `() =>this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText)` or `function() { this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText) }`
P.S. : debounce is not just a setTimeout

Comment: Just a note for others, if you define a debounce function in your render method, it will recreate on every render, making the debounce ineffective. Wrap it in useMemo. https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-throttle-debounce/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_.debounce` is already a carried out function (function returns function ) . Then `_debouncedSearch` should be an attribute of the class , and not method :

```
  _debouncedSearch=  debounce(() => this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText), 1000);
```

instead of :

```
  _debouncedSearch() {
    debounce(this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText), 1000);
  }
```

Also, notice , the first argument of `_.debounce` is a function (`() => this.props.fetchRoutes...`) , not directly `this.props.fetchRoutes...`

Comment: Not sure if this is related. Is this some loader issue? ./src/components/home/Layout.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform.

  29 |   }
  30 | 
> 31 |   _debouncedSearch = debounce(
     |   ^
  32 |     () => this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText),
  33 |     1000
  34 |   );

Comment: BTW, my syntax is right if you are using  the babel plugin : `class properties transform` . However , you are not using it that's why you got `Missing class properties transform....` I recommend to configure your babel to add that plugin and get rid off `constructor`

Answer (score 10):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText: '',
    };
    this._debouncedSearch = debounce(
      () => this.props.fetchRoutes(this.state.searchText),
      1000
    );
  }

  _updateResults(searchText) {
    this.setState({searchText});
    this._debouncedSearch();
  }
```

Here is the fullworking code in case someone needs it!

Answer (score 1):

Recently found this issue helpful. Here's my optimized solution:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

async function fetchData(searchTerm: string) {
  const { data } = await client.query(searchTerm);
  setResult(data);
}

const debounceLoadData = useMemo(() => debounce(fetchData, 700), []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", debounceLoadData(searchTerm));
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", debounceLoadData(searchTerm));
  };
}, [searchTerm]);
```

This will only call the `fetchData()` function once after the user stops typing for 700ms. Then I use `useMemo` to cache every result. If the user searches the same value multiple times it will return the cached value and not invoke the `fetchData()` function more than necessary.